# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.XXX_master' to type 'XXX.MasterPage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, master-pages, .net

I want to access a specific control in a master page from the page which use it so i write the following code line :

```
this.Master.FindControl("pnl_Buttonss").Visible = false;
```

Now

I get the following exception from the page .designer.cs :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage2_master' to type 'GuideUI.MasterPage'.
```

---

```
 public new GuideUI.MasterPage Master {
            get {
                return ((GuideUI.MasterPage)(base.Master));
            }
        }
```

this 's the code which throw the exception .How to fix this error

Comment: How did you fix this? I have an old ASP.NET project that was working for years, but I recently needed to make a change, but now *NONE* of my casts from the Master page work - and none of that code has changed. I suspect a Visual Studio patch changed something or there was a Windows update.

Comment: @jp2code Could U comment a link to the project in github

Comment: I posted it on this site https://forums.asp.net/post/6325472.aspx I have tried posting it here, but it was closed as "off-topic". Sometimes I really hate SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have used the same master page on that page as the one you are casting to.